# Changing 08 to 8 in a python array

Tags: python

I am doing this challenge: https://projecteuler.net/problem=11 in python

As you can see some of the data includes a zero before the actual number.

I am trying to fix this by doing:

```
with open(file) as f:
    numbers = f.read().split(' ')

numbers = [i.lstrip('0') for i in numbers]
```

but this results in '00' being stripped to an empty string. How can I prevent this?

Comment: `int(i)` or `i.lstrip('0') or "0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it instead.

```
>>> str(int('08', 10))
'8'
>>> str(int('00', 10))
'0'
```